# Extraer datos de una db mediate angularjs y ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Estoy intentando extraer los datos de una tabla de mi db mediante ajax y angular.Realice un CRUD con MVC usando asp.net y entity framework, el CRUD no tiene ningún problema, pero al momento de mostrar un dato guardado con angular no no devuelve nada. He consultado en diferentes paginas pero aun así no obtengo el resultado. Estoy trabajando en visual studio 2017

> > Script del js

```
var conductores = angular.module('conductores', []);
conductores.controller('conductoresController', function ($scope, $http) {
     $http.get('/Conductors/Index').then(function (response) {
          $scope.lista = response.data;
     })
})
```

> > Codigo del controlador

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using ajax_test;

namespace ajax_test.Controllers
{
public class ConductorsController : Controller
{
    private Entities db = new Entities();

    // GET: Conductors
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Conductor.ToList());
    }
    // Ajax 
    public ActionResult Listaconductores()
    {
        Entities db = new Entities();
        var data = db.Conductor.ToList();


        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

> > Codigo de HTML

```
@model IEnumerable<ajax_test.Conductor>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}


<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="conductores" ng-controller="conductoresController"></div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col" s6>
        <h2>Conductores</h2>
    </div>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Nombre
            </th>
            <th>
                Apellido
            </th>
            <th>
                Direccion
            </th>
            <th>
                Cedula
            </th>
            <th>
                Telefono
            </th>

        </tr>

        <tr ng-repeat="conductor in lista">

            <td>
                {{conductor.Nombre}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{conductor.Apellido}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{conductor.Direccion}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{conductor.Cedula}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{conductor.Telefono}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Este es el resultado, Claro esta, ya hay datos ingresados en la db
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Espero que estés bien.

El problema que estoy notando en tu código es que tanto en tu vista HTML como en tu script de JavaScript haces referencia a un controlador de nombre **conductoresController** mientras que el nombre del controlador que quieres llamar es **ConductorsController**.

> SCRIPT DEL JS

```
var conductores = angular.module('conductores', []);
conductores.controller('ConductorsController', function ($scope, $http) {
         $http.get('/Conductors/Index').then(function (response) {
             $scope.lista = response.data;
 })
})
```

> HTML

```
@model IEnumerable<ajax_test.Conductor>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}


<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="conductores" ng-controller="ConductorsController"></div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col" s6>
         <h2>Conductores</h2>
    </div>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Nombre
            </th>
            <th>
                Apellido
            </th>
            <th>
                Direccion
            </th>
            <th>
                Cedula
            </th>
            <th>
                Telefono
            </th>

        </tr>

        <tr ng-repeat="conductor in lista">

            <td>
                {{conductor.Nombre}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{conductor.Apellido}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{conductor.Direccion}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{conductor.Cedula}}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{conductor.Telefono}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Además recuerda que JavaScript es un lenguaje Sensitive Case, por lo tanto en tu script deberías llamar al controlador exactamente de la forma como lo nombraste en tu código del controlador.

Comment: Para que la respuesta tenga mayor posibilidad de ser aceptada pon un ejemplo con código

Comment: Acabo de agregar el código de cómo debería ser el llamado del controlador (lo que propongo en la respuesta), muchas gracias por tu sugerencia.

Comment: He realizado el cambio de nombre del controlador como lo dijiste pero aun asi no me devulve los datos de la db. No se si el problema esta en el codigo el ajax

Comment: Puedes agregar a tu GitHub el código de tu proyecto y lo puedo revisar para brindarte una mejor respuesta

Comment: Dale https://github.com/Thomascm19/ajax-test

Comment: Hola Thomas, estoy teniendo problemas para ejecutar tu solución, esto podría tomar más de lo planeado